# awk - max value of a rolling average

Tags: linux, bash, awk, ps

I have a bash command which gives me the highest value in the 9th column of a file:

```
cat "log.txt" | grep 1923 | awk '{print $9}' | sort -n | tail -1
```

log.txt is a log of CPU usage for process 1923 & is measured 10 times per second.

I need to verify that process 1923 never exceeds a certain threshold for more than one second.

Could someone please help me formulate an awk command that:

1. Calculates a rolling 1-second average
2. Tells me the peak value it finds

Many thanks,
Fidel

Comment: I'm confused as to how a one-liner (or grawity's magnificent awk script, for that matter) could produce a "rolling average" if they are manually run against a log ... you'd need to tail the log for that, and an awk script w/ a END clause wouldn't work for printing peak values out.

Comment: Hi tink, the awk script is being run on a file that's not being updated constantly...does that answer your question?

Comment: Heh.  Kind of boils down to semantics, then.  I don't think 'rolling' is a good word in the given situation. :)

Comment: Have you considered using `ulimit` to prevent the command from exceeding a threshold?

Comment: hah, I get you now tinks ;)

Comment: @tink: Modifying the script to print the current peak for every line wouldn't be hard to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# NOTE: This example takes only CPU load as input. Use it like this:
#
#    cat log.txt | awk '$1 == "1923" {print $9}' | awk -f rolling-average.awk

BEGIN {
    freq = 10; sum = 0; max = 0
}

{
    i = NR % freq
    if (NR > freq)
        sum -= data[i]
    sum += (data[i] = $1)
}

NR >= freq {
    avg = sum/freq
    print "average for " NR-freq+1 ".." NR " = " avg
    if (avg > max) {
        max = avg
        pos = NR
    }
}

END {
    print "peak " max " at " pos-freq+1 ".." pos
}
```

**Edit:** Fixed a possible bug and removed the line filtering (which made things more complex than necessary) – now it needs to be given CPU load numbers only. But at least it calculates the average correctly now.

Comment: wow grawity, I'm impressed! Thank you very much!